# How to find the Laplace transform of $\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t^2}$?

Tags: laplace-transform

$$ f(t)=\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t^2} $$          $$  F(S)= ? $$

Comment: Did you read the answers below?:)

Comment: It was helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let

$$F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \, e^{-st} \, dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{t^2} e^{-st} \, dt. $$

The function $f(t)$ satisfies the bound $ f(t) = O(1 \wedge t^{-2})$, thus it is absolutely integrable and we can apply Leibniz's integral to obtain

$$ F''(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-\cos t) \, e^{-st} \, dt = \frac{1}{s} - \frac{s}{s^2 + 1}. $$

Integrating and using the condition $F'(\infty) = 0$, we have

$$ F'(s) = \log s - \log \sqrt{s^2 + 1}. $$

Thus we have

$$F(s) = \int \left\{ \log s - \log \sqrt{s^2 + 1} \right\} \, ds. $$

The first term is easily integrated to yield $s \log s - s$. For the second term, note that

\begin{align*}
-\int \log \sqrt{s^2 + 1} \, ds
&= - s \log \sqrt{s^2 + 1} + \int \frac{s^2}{s^2 + 1} \, ds \\
&= - s \log \sqrt{s^2 + 1} + s - \arctan s + C.
\end{align*}

Combining, we obtain

$$ F(s) = s \log s - s \log \sqrt{s^2 + 1} - \arctan s + C. $$

But since $F(\infty) = 0$, we must have $C = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and therefore

\begin{align*}
F(s)
&= s \log s - s \log \sqrt{s^2 + 1} - \arctan s + \frac{\pi}{2} \\
&= s \log \bigg( \frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2 + 1}} \bigg) + \arctan \left(\frac{1}{s}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Maple agrees with your answer.

Comment: Nicely done. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Besides Dennis's answer, using the following fact may be helpful:

> If $~\mathcal L\left\{ f(t)\right\}=F(s)~$ and Laplace of the function $~g(t)=\dfrac{f(t)}{t}~$ exists, then
>
> $$\mathcal L \left\{\dfrac{f(t)}{t}\right\}=\int\limits_s^{\infty}F(u)\,\mathrm du$$

Comment: Thank you so much.It's helpful.

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
\int\limits_s^\infty F(u)\,\mathrm du
&=\int\limits_s^\infty\int\limits_0^\infty f(t)e^{-ut}\,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm du
\\&=\int\limits_0^\infty f(t)\int\limits_s^\infty e^{-ut}\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dt
\\&=\int\limits_0^\infty f(t)\left.\frac{e^{-ut}}{-t}\right|_s^\infty \,\mathrm dt
\\&=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{f(t)}te^{-st}\,\mathrm dt
\\&=\mathcal L\left\{\frac {f(t)}t \right\}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @UnkleRhaukus: Thanks for the edit. ;-)

Comment: $~\ddot\smile~$

Comment: $\color{blue}{\bf \ddot\smile \quad +1\quad}$

Comment: @amWhy: Yo looked blue yesterday, Amy. :-)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Laplace Transform of $\ds{\fermi\pars{t} \equiv {1 - \cos\pars{t} \over t^{2}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{t}\expo{-st}\,\dd t}
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{t}}
> \pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}x\expo{-tx}\,\dd x}\expo{-st}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd x\,x\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> \expo{-\pars{x + s}t} - \expo{-\pars{x + s - \ic}t}}\,\dd t
> =\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}x\pars{{1 \over x + s} - {1 \over x + s - \ic}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{%
> -\,{s \over x + s} + {s - \ic   \over x + s - \ic}}\,\dd x
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> -\,{s \over x + s} + {\pars{x + s}s + 1   \over \pars{x + s}^{2} + 1}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}\bracks{%
> \half\,s\ln\pars{\bracks{x + s}^{2} + 1 \over \bracks{x + s}^{2}}
> + \arctan\pars{x + s}}_{x = 0}^{x = \Lambda}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large%
> -\,\half\,s\ln\pars{s^{2} + 1 \over s^{2}} + {\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{s}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Probably the only way is to use the definition:
$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t) dt$$
But, at least according to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=Laplace%20transform%20of%28%281-Cos%5Bt%5D%29/t%5E2%29), it has no elementary form.

Comment: WA, as often, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As we know
$$g(s)=\mathcal{L}\left\{1-\cos t\right\}=\mathcal{L}\left\{1\right\}-\mathcal{L}\left\{\cos t\right\}=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{s}{s^2+1}$$
Therefore,
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{1-\cos t}{t}\right\}=\int_{s}^{\infty}g(\sigma)\, d\sigma=\int_{s}^{\infty}
\frac{1}{\sigma}-\frac{\sigma}{\sigma^2+1}\, d\sigma$$
Since
$$\int\frac{1}{\sigma}-\frac{\sigma}{\sigma^2+1}\, d\sigma=\ln \left|\sigma\right|-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\sigma^2+1\right|$$
we have that
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{1-\cos t}{t}\right\}=\int_{s}^{\infty}
\frac{1}{\sigma}-\frac{\sigma}{\sigma^2+1}\, d\sigma=1-\ln \left|\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}\right|$$
Therefore,
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{f\right\}=\int_{s}^{\infty}1-\ln \left|\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+1}}\right|\, d\sigma$$

I don't think you can go any further